How to use proxy that has authentication in selenium-webdriver?
I need help on how to use proxy that has authentication in selenium-webdriver in javascript. If the proxy only use host:port, the webdriver works fine. But if i use proxy like user:pass@host:port, the webdriver cant reach the url.
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

(async function example() {
    const proxyUrl = `http://user:pass@host:port`;

    const opts = new chrome.Options()
        .addArguments(
            `--proxy-server=${proxyUrl}`,
        );

    const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(opts)
        .build();

    try {
        await driver.get("https://ipinfo.io/json");

        const pageSource = await driver.getPageSource();
        
        console.log(pageSource);
    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
}());

And this is what i got when i use proxy that has auth:
<script jstcache="0">
  var loadTimeDataRaw = {
    "details": "Details",
    "errorCode": "ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES",
    "fontfamily": "'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif",
    "fontfamilyMd": "'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif",
    "fontsize": "75%",
    "heading": {
      "hostName": "ipinfo.io",
      "msg": "This site can’t be reached"
    },
    "hideDetails": "Hide details",
    "iconClass": "icon-generic",
    "language": "en",
    "suggestionsDetails": [],
    "suggestionsSummaryList": [],
    "summary": {
      "failedUrl": "https://ipinfo.io/json",
      "hostName": "ipinfo.io",
      "msg": "The webpage at \u003Cstrong jscontent=\"failedUrl\">\u003C/strong> might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."
    },
    "textdirection": "ltr",
    "title": "ipinfo.io"
  };
</script>undefined</body>undefined</html>


Damn I'm having the exact same problem. Any updates?
